# What is being said here that means "it's frowned upon if you're a smoker [in the US]"

Tags: words, expressions, spoken-language, listening

In Shinya Shokudou, S3EP08, a Japanese lady who currently works in New York (but is back home in Japan for a bit) asks the owner of a Shokudou for a cigarette as he's smoking. The owner says "Over in the US, I heard that it's frowned upon if you're a smoker." according to the subtitles, but I can't make out what's being said for the "frowned upon if you're a smoker" part. Anyone have any idea?

Here's the clip: https://files.catbox.moe/8e1f4f.mp4

To me, it sounds like he's saying "Mukou ja, ***aigenka wa katami ga semai*** tte kiku kedo.", but it's the emboldened phrase that I can't find anything relevant about. All I know is "kokoro ga semai" would imply that someone is close-minded about something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It says 愛煙家{あいえんか}は肩身{かたみ}が狭{せま}い. 愛煙家 means literally just *smoke-lover*.

[Jisho](https://jisho.org/word/%E8%82%A9%E8%BA%AB%E3%81%AE%E7%8B%AD%E3%81%84) lists 肩身が狭い as *ashamed*, but to be a bit more precise, it describes the situation where the person feels s/he must squeeze her/himself (taking narrower space) by surrounding pressure. Or more simply the situation makes her/him feel awkward.

Comment: We have a similar metaphor in English; we can say that someone "feels small" (due to shame), or "shrinks away" (from a social situation). Usually it takes a bit of context to justify, though.